# Problem with Request Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, validate-request

In order to display some special text (like html data) I put `validaterequest="false"` in my aspx page. But unfortunatly I'm not even get that text to display.

So how can i display that (Html enabled) content?

Comment: Are you getting an exception when posting HMTL to the page?

Comment: Which version of .NET Framework are you using? Is it 4.0?

Comment: Is the content being sent to the client - do a view source on the page. This should determine if it's a style or server render issue.

Comment: in what sort of control are you trying to show the inserted html? do you have some sample code?

Comment: tring to show in text box, but that text box in grid (panel --> grid --> textbox)

Answer (score 2):

If you experience that validateRequest="false" has no effect, it may be helped by setting this in web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

Which reverts to the behavior of the ASP.NET 2.0 request validation feature.

Comment: I'm using 2.0 only. Also getting this error Unrecognized attribute 'requestValidationMode'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display the html text. Place a asp:Literal contol on the form where you want to display the text. e.g.

```
ASPX:
<asp:Literal ID="outputHtml" runat="Server">

CS:

outputHtml.Text = your_var_having_html;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the TextBox is in a databound control (Repeater/GridView/etc.) and you bind the data on every postback the TextBox will lose it's contents, because all contents of the control are recreated. Use `if(!Page.IsPostBack){/*code*/}` to make sure it only databinds on first load.